# Transferring windows message data from C dll hook file to python for data analysis

Tags: python, windows, winapi, dll, ipc

I have to implement IPC between my python file and the associated dll file in C. For this i would like to use ZeroMQ. Now i am really struggling to establish a connection between the files using the example code provided by zmq. I am trying to connect to the server, but python gives me WinError 126. Even though i declared the function correctly.

DLL:

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "pch.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <zmq.h>
HHOOK tHook;
HMODULE hinstDLL;
LRESULT CALLBACK meconnect(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (code == HC_ACTION) {
        LPMSG data = (LPMSG)lParam;
        UINT message = data->message;
        switch (message)
        {
        case WM_POINTERUPDATE:
            if (!IS_POINTER_INCONTACT_WPARAM(wParam))
                break;
        case WM_POINTERDOWN:
        case WM_POINTERUP:
            POINTER_INFO pointerInfo = {};
            GetPointerInfo(GET_POINTERID_WPARAM(wParam), &pointerInfo);

            break;
        }
    }
    return(CallNextHookEx(tHook, code, wParam, lParam));
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) BOOL ConnectServer() {
    printf("Connecting to hello world server…\n");
    void* context = zmq_ctx_new();
    void* requester = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_REQ);
    zmq_connect(requester, "tcp://localhost:5555");
    return TRUE;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) BOOL SetHook()
{
    tHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, meconnect, hinstDLL, 0);

    if (tHook == NULL)
        return FALSE;
    else
        return TRUE;
}
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) BOOL UnHook()
{
    return UnhookWindowsHookEx(tHook);
}


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID lpReserved
)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        hinstDLL = hModule;
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Python File:

```
def pointer_msg_loop():
    global lib
    lib = cdll.LoadLibrary(r'C:\Users\Braun\Documents\BA_Thesis\ba-oliver-braun-logging-tool-code\MessagesDll\x64\Debug\HOOKDLL.dll')
    print(lib)
    res = lib.SetHook()
    res = lib.ConnectServer()
    pythoncom.PumpMessages()
    res = lib.UnHook()
```

Why do SetHook() and UnHook() work, but not ConnectServer(). I am sorry i am really bad at C.
this is the error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Braun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Braun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Braun/Documents/BA_Thesis/ba-oliver-braun-logging-tool-code/VirtualTrackingTool.py", line 261, in pointer_msg_loop
    lib = cdll.LoadLibrary(r'C:\Users\Braun\Documents\BA_Thesis\ba-oliver-braun-logging-tool-code\MessagesDll\x64\Debug\HOOKDLL.dll')
  File "C:\Users\Braun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 442, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Users\Braun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. It works for like this: `>>> res = lib.ConnectServer()
Connecting to hello world server…`.  Could you confirm which line cause this error?

Comment: i edited the exception i am getting in

Comment: Your DLL is in C or C++?

Comment: It is in C, i resolved the issue now by putting the zmq dll into my main directory, which seems to work

Comment: Glad to hear you get it working. Post an answer and accept it. It will help for others are searching on this issue.